# Creating a round dice and detect a number which appears as a result at the specified postition when the dice stops rolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, image-rotation, dice

I am developing an application in which there is one round dice like: 
When I click on the center of the image it rotates

in first image is before rotation means initial state and second image is after rotation image and in this number 3 is shown on the result pointer.
My problem is how to detect that the result if the dice roll is number 3.I want the number which appears on the result arrow.

On button click I do :-

create a random number which acts like a angle.
and rotate the image to that angle.

```
-(IBAction)diceButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    float angle=arc4random()%360;
    NSLog(@"%f",angle);
    toAngle=angle;
    if (fromAngle+toAngle<360) {
        toAngle=fromAngle+toAngle;
    }
    else
    {
        if (toAngle<30) {

            toAngle=angle+30;
        }
        else
        {
            toAngle=angle;
        }
    }
     [self rotateDiceMethod];

  }


My logic for image rotation:-

  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut]; 
   diceNumbers.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(startTransform,toAngle);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    startTransform=diceNumbers.transform;
    fromAngle=toAngle;
```

Please anybody help me how to know which is the result of my dice or what approach should I follow to do achieve my required functionality.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know the exact amount of angle rotated.
The simplest way is to detect the rotated angle and get corresponding value.

For example:

```
- (int)getDiceValue  {
   // Total 6 number, so 360/6 = 60 deg for each number and make sure totalRotatedAngle is from 0 to 359
   if (totalRotatedAngle < 30 || totalRotatedAngle >= 300)  {return 1;}
   else if (totalRotatedAngle >= 30 && totalRotatedAngle < 90)  {return 6;}
   ...
}
```

One more thing, CGAffineTransformRotate take radian values as argument. So you have to convert you rotate angle from degree to radian before transformation.

Comment: thanks for your quick help.Can you plaese tell all the conditions , I am not getting how to set other condidtions like this:- else if (totalRotatedAngle >= 30 && totalRotatedAngle < 90)  {return 6;}

Comment: The angle is start from your arrow in clockwise direction. Since you have 6 sectors and each sector is 60 deg. Your initial number is 1. Which is in the range of 330 to 30. So for number 6, the range should 30 to 90; number 4 is 90 to 150 etc. You should be able to calculate the rest :)

Comment: HI , I have calculated another conditions also as;-- (int)getDiceValue  {
    // Total 6 number, so 360/6 = 60 deg for each number and make sure totalRotatedAngle is from 0 to 359
    if (toAngle < 30 || toAngle >= 300)  {return 1;}
    else if (toAngle >= 30 && toAngle < 90)  {return 6;}
    else if (toAngle >= 90 && toAngle < 150)  {return 4;}
    else if (toAngle >= 150 && toAngle < 210)  {return 3;}
    else if (toAngle >= 210 && toAngle < 270)  {return 5;}
    else if (toAngle >= 270 && toAngle < 330)  {return 2;}


}

Comment: when I checked, the value are getting wrong. Like for angle 183  the pointer is showing value 6 and the value received from the method is returning 3.Please see if I have made wrong pair of conditions.

Comment: CGAffineTransformRotate take radian values as argument. So you have to convert you rotate angle from degree to radian before transformation. radians = totalRotatedAngle/180.0*M_PI;